# How to install Netbeans 10 on Windows 10

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-10

I just noticed that NetBeans 10 was released on december 2018.

However, I can't figure out how to install it on windows.

Is it even compatible for windows 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just download the binaries package from https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html , unzip it and start it with `\netbeans\bin\netbeans[64].exe`

Comment: lol, why are they not just making a normal installer which places a shortcut to the desctop?

Comment: @Black They are working on it: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/1251af6dd35056081e204a6895649c4b78aeabfbef6e5b06174668a0@%3Cdev.netbeans.apache.org%3E During the transition to Apache there were other things more important.